# How to play/pause Facebook embedded video without using mouse

Tags: javascript, facebook, tizen, tizen-web-app

I am developing web app for TV platform with YouTube, Vimeo and Facebook video players. All players have it's own api which works fine. But for some reason Facebook video doesn't work on Tizen TV.  I've decided to use facebook iframe video (not JavaScript SDK). Its works, but i cant use mouse on TV platform, so i need some js methods to start, play, pause video.
Can i use postmessages to communicate with Facebook iframe? Smth like this?

`$('iframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');`

Problem is that i don't know right methods to play pause video. `"func":"pauseVideo"` doesn't work for Facebook

Maybe someone know why on Earth Facebook SDK doesn't work on Tizen platform?

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: No you can not use postMessage. Use the Javascript SDK.

Comment: It would be better to use Javascript SDK

Comment: I would like to use Javascript SDK. And I am using it for other TV platforms. But on Tizen apps are installed under the file:// protocol (not http or https that is required ), and so there is no referrer on the API requests. Facebook JavaScript SDK is designed only for Web. I can't make it work on Tizen TV

Comment: _“and so there is no referrer on the API requests”_ - and you are sure that is actually the cause of the problem …? If so, how exactly did you figure that, did you get error messages anywhere saying that this is refusing to work because of no referrer?

Comment: "It would be better to use Javascript SDK " - the problem is this doesnt seem to be compatible on cases where the video tag is added dynamically like *ngIf in angular